# Iterated forcing and non-existance of a model $N$ such that $\langle G_n : n \in \omega \rangle \in N$ and $\text{o}(N) = \text{o}(M)$.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I have encountered the following exercise in kunen's forcing chapter and i have only partially solved it. Any hint or sketch would be very helpful.

---

> Let $\mathbb{P} \in M$ be non-atomic. Let $$M = M_0 \subset M_1 \subset \dots \subset M_n \subset \dots \hspace{0.5cm} (n \in \omega)\\$$ such that $M_{n+1} = M_n[G_n]$ for some $G_n$ which is $\mathbb{P}\text{-generic}$ over $M_n$. Show that $\cup_nM_n$ cannot satisfy the Powerset Axiom. Furthermore, show that the $G_n$ may be chosen so that there is no c.t.m. $N$ for ZFC with $\langle G_n : n \in \omega \rangle \in N$ and $\text{o}(N) = \text{o}(M)$. Hint: $\{n : p \in G_n\}$ can code $\text{o}(M)$.

---

By non-atomic we mean: $$\forall p \in \mathbb{P} \hspace{0.1cm} \exists q,r( q \le p \wedge r \le p \wedge q \bot r ) \\$$ And $\text{o}(M) = \text{Ord} \cap M$.

---

Now we can easily see that $\mathbb{P}$ can have no power set in $\cup_nM_n$ because if it had a power set then it would be in some $M_n$ but then it couldn't have $G_n$ inside it because $G_n \not \in M_n$ and clearly $G_n \subset \mathbb{P}$, a contradiction. 
 
Now for the second part i have so far chosen some natural $G_n$ by using the fact $\mathbb{P}$ is non-atomic like this: Choose some random $p\in \mathbb{P}$ and choose a generic $G_0$ such that $p \in G_0$. Now we know there are $q,r$ such that $( q \le p \wedge r \le p \wedge q \bot r )$ and hence both of them can't be in $G_0$, so choose one like $q$ now construct $G_1$ such that $q \in G_1$. Do this for all $n \in \omega$. At this stage i don't know how to code the ordinals of $M$ in sets like $F_p = \{n : p \in G_n\}$. Any kind of hint would be very helpful.$$$$Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Coding an ordinal into a set of integers simply means that when we take some "canonical enough" encoding of $\omega^2\to\omega$ (e.g. the Cantor pairing function, or really any reasonable pairing function), then the set of integers actually codes a relation which is a well-ordering of its domain. Once we match it to an order type, we get some ordinal. So you want to code the ordinal $o(M)$ into the sequence of the generics.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, But the thing that i don't understand is that such an encoding(coding $o(M)$ into the integers) can't be in $M$ since $M$ sees $o(M)$ as a proper class. So how can i argue that this encoding exists in $N$?

Comment: Separation, of course. If $N$ is a model of ZFC it is contains the sequence of generics, it also contains sets definable from the sequence.

Comment: @Asafkaragila, is the following correct? Consider a bijection between $\omega \times \omega$ and $\omega$ and choose an $X \subset \omega$ such that $f^{-1}(X) \cong o(M)$. Now force $M$ to have $X$ as a subset of $\omega$(How?). Now since $\mathbb{P}$ is infinite, we have an injection, $h: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}$, extend this injection to all of $\omega$ with $h(n) = 1_P$ where $1_P$ is the greatest element of $\mathbb{P}$. Now the set $f^{-1}(\{n : h(n) \in G_n\})$ has ordertype $\ge o(M)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can code any subset, $X$, of $\omega$ as follows: take your incompatible $q$ and $r$. Now choose $G_n$ each time such that $q\in G_n$ if $n\in X$ and $r\in G_n$ if $n\notin X$.
Then $X$ is definable from $q$ and the sequence $\langle G_n:n\in\omega\rangle$.